# Object not found while knitting in R Studio

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to knit using R studio but keep getting an error

> Error in summary(diamonds) : object 'diamonds' not found Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> summary Execution halted

This is my code,

````
```{r}
   summary(diamonds)
```
````

While I run the above code it works fine but when I try to knit it says the object is not found. Although when I use the `cars` datset, I don't have such problems. I understand the `diamonds` dataset is a part of the `ggplot2` package and I have installed the package as well.

I have gone through suggestions to use

```
knit2html('filename.Rmd')
knit('filename.Rmd')
```

I have also tried

````
```{r include = TRUE}
   summary(diamonds)
```
````

Comment: Did you load the `ggplot2` package? `diamonds` is not available in base `R`. When you knit the code, execution happens in a different environment. You probably loaded `ggplot2` in you global environment but not in the code chunk

Comment: Hi @Sumedh, Yeah, I have loaded the ggplot2 package.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the package inside the code chunk before knitting it.

````
```{r}

   library(ggplot2)
   summary(diamonds)

```
````

Comment: Thank you @Sumedh.. I had included `library(ggplot2)` earlier but had it commented out. This works fine.